Appling a Hadamard gate to a qubit in density matrix form
If a Hadamard gate is applied to a qubit that is in the state $|0\rangle$, then it becomes the state $$|+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|0\rangle+|1\rangle\right)$$ In density matrix form, this state is:
$$\rho=|+\rangle\langle+|=\frac{1}{2}\left(|0\rangle+|1\rangle\right)\left(\langle0|+\langle1|\right)$$
But, if we start with the state $|0\rangle$ in density matrix form, $|0\rangle\langle0|$, and then apply a Hadamard gate, we get:
$$\rho=|+\rangle\langle0|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|0\rangle+|1\rangle\right)\langle0|$$
Why is there a discrepancy between these two results? Which is correct?

Applying a unitary $U$ to a state $\psi$ is expressed by $$U\psi.$$
Applying a unitary to a density matrix $\rho$ is expressed by
$$U\rho U^\dagger.$$

to clarify why this is the case: If $\vert\psi;^\prime\rangle = U\vert\psi\rangle$, then $\rho^\prime = \vert\psi;^\prime\rangle\langle\psi;^\prime\vert = U\vert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\vert U^\dagger$

Yes absolutely. The same (or rather its "dual") is also encoded in the Heisenberg equation of motion.
